# Shortest Hello World program with no semi colons

Tags: code-golf, c#

I recently saw some questions on SO that asked if you could make a Hello World program without using any semi colons using C#. The challenge is to do this again, but in the shortest  amount of code possible!

Comment: I assume this is meant to be a language-specific challenge?  Otherwise there are plenty of languages where this task would be trivial.  (For example, `'Hello World'` is a valid GolfScript program that prints `Hello World`. Although [HQ9+](http://esolangs.org/wiki/HQ9%2B) will easily beat it.)

Comment: @llmari Sorry, yes, I have updated question. I would have tagged it C# but it doesn't exist and I don't have the rep to create it, thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## C#, 76

```
class X{static void Main(){if(System.Console.Write("Hello, World!")is X){}}}
```

I tried this in my VS2012 and it works just fine, even though it is quite a surprise that you can apply the `is` operator to `void`...

Answer (score 15):

## C# 85 chars

```
class H{static void Main(){if(System.Console.Out.WriteAsync("Hello, world!")is H){}}}
```

Comment: Which .NET version is this? [.NET 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter_methods.aspx) doesn't seem to contain a definition for TextWriter.WriteAsync().

Comment: @primo [.NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158638%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does.

Answer (score 12):

### C# (114)

```
class M{static void Main(){if(typeof(System.Console).GetMethods()[78].Invoke(null,new[]{"Hello, world!"})is M){}}}
```

Note that the proper index for `Write(string)`/`WriteLine(string)` may be different on your system.  However, since there are only 106 methods total, I'm almost certain either `Write(string)` or `WriteLine(string)` will be a two-digit index number on every system, so the character count should be generally valid.

Demo: http://ideone.com/5npky (`Write` method is apparently index 23 here)

Comment: This solution is brilliant. +1

Comment: I also thought is was ironic that after putting it together, it came out exactly 1 character shorter than yours :)

Comment: Can save three characters by changing `null` to `0`. Get a nice character count of 111 :)

Answer (score 8):

## 115 Bytes

```
class H{static void Main(){if(((System.Action)(()=>System.Console.Write("Hello, world!"))).DynamicInvoke()is H){}}}
```

It's likely possible to produce something a bit shorter, but I'm pretty sure that you're going to need make some sort of asynchronous call.

Answer (score 4):

## C# <s>96</s> <s>95</s> 94 chars

A bit of a cheat, but works if you have IronRuby installed:

```
class P{static void Main(){if(IronRuby.Ruby.CreateEngine().Execute("puts'Hello World'")>1){}}}
```

Comment: You can save 1 char by replacing `==` with a one-character comparison operator.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I've updated the code. Thanks for this great suggestion!

Comment: I also removed the space between `puts` and the string. `puts'Hello World'` is valid ruby code