# Write 'hello world' to standard output without using certain common words - C# only

Tags: code-golf, c#

The challenge is to write the string `hello world` to your processes standard output, using as few characters of code as possible.

The following restrictions apply:

- The following words may not appear anywhere in the code in any casing (this includes as part of another word)

  1. Console
  2. Debug
  3. Write
  4. Print
  5. Line
  6. Put
- Your code must compile as C# 4/4.5
- No external libraries are permitted.
- Your process may not spawn any new processes.

A working (but not necessarily the shortest) solution will be provided after a number of answers have been provided.

The winner is the author of the shortest code by character count that satisfies the above criteria.

Comment: There is at least one solution to this in the answers to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5550/shortest-hello-world-program-with-no-semi-colons

Comment: @PeterTaylor - none of the C# answers posted for that challenge satisfy the word usage restriction.

Comment: [w0lf's one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5558/194) does. There are also some answers in http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/307/obfuscated-hello-world which demonstrate a technique which could be applied to the trivial hello world program (and which I see Johannes Kuhn has used in his answer).

Comment: @JohannesKuhn how is it a duplicate? The restrictions are completely different.

Comment: Not exactly. You may violate 1 rule of the other question, and for C# it have to be rule 1 (`class` is needed). All of the words you list here except `put` violate rule 2. That means the difference is that on the other question `put` and other languages are allowed and here the characters `eor0127` are allowed. Not very big.

Answer (score 3):

## 75 chars

New answer, new approach.

```
class M{static void Main(){System.\u0043onsole.\u0057rite("hello world");}}
```

It looks like you can hide every character with a `\uXXXX` sequence. Which makes this thing...
Easy.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I try my luck:

### 118 chars

```
class M{static void Main(){System.Type.GetType("System.\x43onsole").GetMethods()[78].Invoke(0,new[]{"hello world"});}}
```

Based on [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5550/shortest-hello-world-program-with-no-semi-colons/5560#5560) solution.

[Idone](http://ideone.com/IFZHrF)

As noted in the original answer, the index of the Write method might be different on your system.

Comment: 'Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32'' You were right about the index not being the same. Since it doesn't run for me I can't accept this particular answer.

Comment: It runs on Idone. You have to change the index. Try 78.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my current best that runs anywhere:

### 158 Characters

```
using System;class M{static void Main(){Type.GetType("System.\x43onsole").GetMethod("\x57rite\x4cine",new[]{typeof(string)}).Invoke(0,new[]{"hello world"});}}
```

`.Invoke` ignores the first param entirely if its a static method, so you can use `0` instead of `null` to save 3 characters.

Additionally, a variation that bans the use of the `\` character:

### 234 Characters

```
using System;using System.Linq;class M{static void Main(){Func<string,string>f=(i)=>new string(i.Reverse().ToArray());Type.GetType(f("elosnoC.metsyS")).GetMethod(f("eniLetirW"),new[]{typeof(string)}).Invoke(0,new[]{"hello world"});}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## 183 chars

Without reflection "cheats"! (but using the deprecated overload of FileStream to avoid using SafeFilePointer)

```
using System;using System.IO;public class M{static void Main(){new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String("SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=")).CopyTo(new FileStream(new IntPtr(-11),(FileAccess)2));}}
```